# Internal direct sum of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $\{(1,1,0), (0,1,1)\}$. Find a subspace $W$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $\mathbb{R}^3 = U \oplus W$.

As I am having an examination tomorrow, it would be really helpful if one could explain the methodology for doing this problem. I am mostly interested in the methodology, rather than the result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see that $W$ must be one-dimensional? So you are just looking for a single (non-zero) vector that's not in $U$ --- then let $W$ be the span of that vector.

Comment: My main issue is how to show that $\mathbb{R}^3 = U + W$.

Comment: You'll have three linearly independent vectors --- the two that span $U$, and the one that spans $W$ --- so you get everything in ${\bf R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a subspace $U \subseteq V$ and you want a complement $W$ so that $U \oplus W = V$.  Then first find a basis $\{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ of $U$.  Then extend this to a basis $\{u_1, \ldots, u_n, w_1, \ldots, w_m\}$ of $V$.  The complement is the subspace spanned by those additional vectors,
$$W = \mathrm{span}\{w_1, \ldots, w_m\}.$$

So for the specific problem above you need to extend $\{(1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e., you just need to find a single vector not contained in $U$.  Then $W$ will be the line spanned by that vector.